Set of all maps 'between' composition of bijections is bijection?
Let $X,Y$ be finite sets such that $X\sim\{1,\dots, m\}$ and $Y\sim\{1,\dots, n\}$. Let $\sigma :\mathbb{N}_{m} \rightarrow X$ and $\tau :Y\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{n}$ be bijections. Let $\mathrm{Map}(X,Y)$ denote the set of all maps from $X$ to $Y$. Now, let
\begin{align*}
  \phi: \mathrm{Map}(X,Y)\rightarrow\mathrm{Map}(\mathbb{N}_{m},\mathbb{N}_{n})
 \end{align*}
be defined as
\begin{align*}
  \forall f\in \mathrm{Map}(X,Y):\varphi(f)=\tau\circ f\circ\sigma 
 \end{align*}
Then $\phi$ is also a bijection. But why? I can't figure it out.

What have you tried so far?

The first things I checked was if $\phi$ is injective and surjective. That's where I encountered the first issues: $\tau$ and $\sigma$ might be bijective but what if $g\in\mathrm{Map}(X,Y)$ maps every $x\in X$ to the same $y_{0}\in Y$? Then $\varphi(g)$ will be the same for all $x\in{1,\dots, m}$. I guess I'm having issues with the definition of $\phi$.

Maybe I also got lost in the wrong details...  So, I guess $\phi$ is surjective iff $\mathrm{img} \phi=\mathrm{Abb}(\mathbb{N}{m},\mathbb{N}{n})$ and injective iff $\phi(f)=\phi(g)\Rightarrow f=g$.

$\phi$ is a function between finite sets so it is sufficient to check injectivity (or surjectivity) only. If you would want to check injectivity, then you can use the characterization you wrote above and use a certain property that $\tau$ and $\sigma$ have as bijections.

Oh right, on equinumerous finite sets we have bijective iff injective iff surjective. didn't think about that. So let $\varphi(f)=\varphi(g)$. Then $\tau \circ f\circ \sigma=\tau\circ g\circ \sigma$. Since $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are bijective, there are inverses $\tau^{-1}$ and $\sigma^{-1}$. therefore $\tau^{-1}\circ\tau \circ f\circ\sigma\circ \sigma^{-1}=\tau^{-1}\circ\tau\circ g\circ\sigma\circ\sigma^{-1}$, i.e. $f=g$, therefore $\phi$ is injective and, indeed, bijective.
